# Add debounce on top of validateConnection in JointJs

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, jointjs, debouncing

I'm struggling with a graph composed by nodes and links in JointJS

I want to prevent the creation of specific links between nodes on the base of some rules (eg. to avoid loops).

To do so I implemented some checks inside the validateConnection property of my paper.

The problem is that these checks can take some time to be performed, in general, longer than the frequency with which the validateConnection function is performed (that is each time the mouse changes position).

So I thought about waiting for a new check until the previous one has been completed. Unfortunately, in this way the solution is highly affected by deadlock problems.

So my last idea is to debounce the checking function. But I'm still not 100% satisfied. Indeed I will need the checking function to be evaluated entirely, and that the property validateConnection sets at the end of this checking.

In there you have the code:

```
validateConnection: _.debounce(function(cellViewS, magnetS, cellViewT, magnetT, end, linkView) {
    if(checkTopologicalRules())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
},100),
snapLinks: { radius: 35 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized that removing the snapLink property I avoid the bouncing behavior.